# what format language is used on data files?

Tags: data-recovery

for learning porposes im trying to read a data file stored on data \cache\Cache but i dont seem to find a proper program to see the original code in it or maybe im just not using the correct language program. any help would be great  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Most Android apps memorize data in SQLite databases, but it's up to us app developers. Any app can use different file formats, even custom ones.

Comment: Oh gosh, did you just try to paste binary data into a comment?

Comment: sorry if i cant do that , i was just trying to give you a sample becausec  im really tired of searching a way to open it